# Java 11 , why do we need an annotation on the lambda parameter?

Tags: java, lambda

As you know, Java 11 added the ability to use the **var** in the parameters of lambda so that you can add annotation, but here I tried to get it in runtime, but since the lambda is not a full-fledged class with its method, it is not there.

To be noted, it works well with anonymous class.

With anonymous class - Output is:

```
[[@test.MyAnnotation()]]
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException {
        Consumer<Integer> consumer = new Consumer<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(@MyAnnotation Integer integer) {
                System.out.println(integer + 1);
            }
        };

        foo(consumer);
    }

    public static void foo(Consumer<Integer> consumer) throws NoSuchMethodException {
        Method method = consumer.getClass().getMethod("accept", Object.class);
        Annotation[][] parameterAnnotations = method.getParameterAnnotations();
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(parameterAnnotations));
    }
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface MyAnnotation {

}
```

With lambda - Output is:

```
 [[]]
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException {
        Consumer<Integer> consumer = (@MyAnnotation var integer) -> System.out.println(integer + 1);

        foo(consumer);
    }

    public static void foo(Consumer<Integer> consumer) throws NoSuchMethodException {
        Method method = consumer.getClass().getMethod("accept", Object.class);
        Annotation[][] parameterAnnotations = method.getParameterAnnotations();
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(parameterAnnotations));
    }
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface MyAnnotation {

}
```

Do you have any explanation?

Comment: [Please don't post pictures of code.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3890632)

Comment: You have personal information in your code pictures. Please remove them. I just found you on facebook.

Comment: Removed picture because of personal information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotations can be used in the source code to provide additional information, and with annotation processing.

I am not sure if this is useful at runtime. A dump of the bytecode suggest the annotation isn't recorded.

```
  // access flags 0x9
  public static main([Ljava/lang/String;)V throws java/lang/NoSuchMethodException 
    // parameter  args
   L0
    LINENUMBER 11 L0
    INVOKEDYNAMIC accept()Ljava/util/function/Consumer; [
      // handle kind 0x6 : INVOKESTATIC
      java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite;
      // arguments:
      (Ljava/lang/Object;)V, 
      // handle kind 0x6 : INVOKESTATIC
      Main.lambda$main$0(Ljava/lang/Integer;)V, 
      (Ljava/lang/Integer;)V
    ]
    ASTORE 1
   L1
    LINENUMBER 13 L1
    ALOAD 1
    INVOKESTATIC Main.foo (Ljava/util/function/Consumer;)V
   L2
    LINENUMBER 14 L2
    RETURN
   L3
    LOCALVARIABLE args [Ljava/lang/String; L0 L3 0
    LOCALVARIABLE consumer Ljava/util/function/Consumer; L1 L3 1
    // signature Ljava/util/function/Consumer<Ljava/lang/Integer;>;
    // declaration: java.util.function.Consumer<java.lang.Integer>
    MAXSTACK = 1
    MAXLOCALS = 2
```

If I run the following it gets nothing.

```
 strings Main.class | grep MyAnn
```

Comment: in my opinion it’s even impossible to take it through annotation processing, then it doesn’t make any sense at all I don’t think that it’s worth using just for information, this is not the place in lambda.

Comment: @Tix This issue might be related https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8057688

Comment: Has nothing changed since JDK 12/13? Is it still impossible to fetch annotation from lambda at runtime?

Comment: @MikhailKholodkov This annotation was not available at runtime regardless of Retention. It is for source code only, making it pretty useless IMHO.